# Incompatible types in return?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Incompatible types in return ?

file.h

```
struct typeCSVFile {
    NSString *nssPath;
    NSString *nssData;

    NSString ***p_nssData;//
    int iRows;
    int iCols;
};

....

struct typeCSVFile structCSVFile;

....

-(struct structCSVFile) fileCSVRead;
```

file.m

```
-(struct structCSVFile) fileCSVRead{

    ...

    return structCSVFile; // <-- Incompatible types in return
}
```

Comment: How did you declare structCSVFile in fileCSVRead?

Comment: I had put it in the header file... see above

Comment: I am getting docked for asking a question about my code ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly, you mean:

```
 -(struct typeCSVFile) fileCSVRead;
```

and:

```
-(struct typeCSVFile) fileCSVRead{
    ...
    return structCSVFile;
}
```

The type name is `struct typeCSVFile`, while `structCSVFile` is an instance of that type. You could also think of using `typedef` to get rid of the `struct` part:

```
typedef struct typeCSVFile typeCSVFile;
```